# dynamically create prototypes and push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, prototype

I'm trying to dynamically create objects of 'test' that are pushed to an array, I know the code below doesn't work, it's for reference to help solve my problem:

```
var test = (function(){
    var blah;

    test.prototype.getNumber=function(){
        return blah;
    }
    test.prototype.setNumber=function(val){
        blah=val;
    }
});

var array=(function(){
    var array[];

    array.prototype.get=function(index){
        return array[index];
    }
    array.prototype.set=function(obj){
        array.push(obj);
    }

});

var objArray=new array();

for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    objArray.set({
        setNumber(5);
    }=new test());
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem/question?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically create objects of 'test' that are pushed to an array and I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to create your constructor functions properly. It seems you want to simulate private properties by using local variables and closures. In that case you have to assign the methods to the instance itself, not the prototype:

```
this.setNumber = function(){
    return blah;
};
// instead of
// test.prototype.setNumber = ...;
```

The same for `array`.

To add an instance, all you have to do is create a new `test` instance and call its `setNumber` method:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    var obj = new test();
    obj.setNumber(5);
    objArray.set(obj);
}
```

---

Note: Constructor function names usually start with a capital letter.